# Add select all checkbox for mui-datatables data as object( custom columns)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mui-datatable

I have trouble to add a checkbox for select all in mui-datatables when my data is object format(custom columns) instead like an array with strings like a lot of samples out there.
Following by the documentation [here](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables#customize-columns), I tried use `customHeadRender` function, but it's not get called, I tried to use `customToolbar`, it will load select all checkbox, but that trigger when you select row, I need that checkbox on page load.

Thank you

Here's [codesanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-flower-3y4j3?file=/src/Sample.js)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `selectableRowsHeader: true,` in your `options` prop and you will be fine.

```js
 ...
   const options = {
      filterType: "textField",
      fixedHeader: true,
      sort: true,
      search: true,
      selectableRows: "multiple",
      responsive: "scrollMaxHeight",
      rowsPerPage: 15,
      rowHove: true,
      selectableRowsHeader: true, //<---------- this should be true (not false)
 ...
```

Working [demo is here](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-table-select-all-checkbox-fix-ogojs?file=/src/Sample.js)

Comment: hi  - did you try it? did it help?

Comment: It's working! I can't believe I miss that. Thank you so much. Take me hours trying to get customHeader to work I want. Thank you so much!!!